# Confusion with using grep with *?

Tags: command-line, grep

I was recently in a conversation with a coworker while he was in his shell, when I saw him do something like `ls -l | grep asdf*`.

"Why the glob?" I asked him. "It's just the way I always do it," he replied.

I didn't immediately see any problems, but it still felt wrong. When I tried it myself later, I saw different behaviors:

```
--> ls -l | grep ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22896 Nov 19  2012 false
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  105840 Nov 19  2012 ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   44640 Nov 19  2012 lsblk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    6272 Nov 19  2012 lsmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   31912 Nov 19  2012 ntfsls

--> ls -l | grep ls*
Binary file lsblk matches
Binary file lsmod matches
```

What on earth is happening here? I figured at worst, grep would treat it as the regex `l(s*)` and give me every occurence of `l`, but this input doesn't even show up in the ls! (I'm running this from `/bin`).

What does grep do when you put a glob after your search string? Should I tell my coworker to stop doing this in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `grep ls*`, the **shell** first expands `ls*` to a list of matching files in the current directory, so the command becomes

```
ls -l | grep ls lsblk lsmod
```

In this case, `grep` will ignore standard input and treat the first argument `ls` as a pattern to be matched **inside** the files `lsblk` and `lsmod`, just as though you'd typed `grep ls lsblk lsmod` (presumably in `/bin`):

```
$ grep ls lsblk lsmod
Binary file lsblk matches
Binary file lsmod matches
```

---

On the other hand, if there are no glob matches in the current directory and the shell's `nullglob` option is not set, then `ls*` will be left **un**expanded, so that `grep` sees `ls*` and matches any file **names** matching `l` followed by zero or more `s` characters (basically any filename with an `l` in it) e.g.:

```
$ pwd
/home/steeldriver
$ echo ls*
ls*
```

(there are no files matching the shell glob `ls*` in my home directory); then

```
$ ls /bin | grep 'ls*'
bzless
chacl
false
.
.
.
zless
```

tl;dr don't do that

Comment: Does `grep` ignore stdin then? It doesn't even pay attention to what was piped in? Also if I run `ls -l /bin | grep ls*` the result looks like it's matching regex `l(s*)`, is there an explanation for that?

Comment: @scohe001 yes I believe that's the case: as `man grep` says: *"If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given, grep searches standard input."*. In the second case, unless your shell's `nullglob` is set, then **if there are no matching files in your current directory**, then the shell will leave `ls*` *un*expanded, which `grep` will then treat as a regex matching `l` followed by zero or more `s`s.

Answer (score 3):

To be more safe your co-worker should use:

```
ls -l | grep "asdf*"
```

to process the piped output, using quotes we are skipping shell file expansions, so we are saying that look for lines with `asd` followed by zero or more `f`, a better use case is:

```
ls -l | grep "asdf.*"
```

The other thing to mention is that if there wasn't any file in current directory matching the pattern it will be considered as it is by `grep`, most of the times that's what is happens.

Also note that parsing `ls` output is [not a good thing to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).